# Spring DataMongoDB unique index with partialfilter raises DuplicateKeyException

Tags: mongodb, spring-data

I have a Mongo collection to maintain a record of jobs and their state. I want to ensure that only one job name can have a ACTIVE state. I created a unique index like this:

```
        IndexFilter onlyActive = PartialIndexFilter.of(Criteria.where("state").is("ACTIVE"));
        mongoTemplate.indexOps(DownloadJob.class)
        .ensureIndex(
            new Index().unique().on("name", Sort.Direction.ASC).on("state", null).partial(onlyActive)
        );
```

At runtime Spring causes this to be set up:

```
INDEX    [conn3] build index on: test.download_jobs properties: { v: 2, unique: true, key: { name: 1, state: -1 }, name: "name_1_state_-1", ns: "test.download_jobs", partialFilterExpression: { state: "ACTIVE" } }
```

My confusion arises from a case where there is a "timed out" job and an "active" one. If the "active" one is changed to "timed out" I get a duplicate key exception. This test illustrates it and my only workaround so far:

```
    @Test
    public void createActiveJobThenSetTimedOut() throws Exception {

        DownloadJob job1 = new DownloadJob();
        job1.setName(NAME);
        job1.setState(State.ACTIVE);

        DownloadJob job2 = new DownloadJob();
        job2.setName(NAME);
        job2.setState(State.TIMEOUT);

        downloadJobRepository.save(job1);
        downloadJobRepository.save(job2);

        DownloadJob reRead1 = downloadJobRepository.findByNameAndState(NAME, State.ACTIVE).orElseThrow();
        DownloadJob copyOf1 = new DownloadJob();
        copyOf1.setId(reRead1.getId());
        copyOf1.setName(reRead1.getName());
        copyOf1.setState(State.TIMEOUT);
        /*
         * NOTE - I do not know why this causes a duplicate key - it's the same object ID as
         * was just read back. If this is changed to change the state in reRead1 and that is
         * saved there will not be an exception.
         */
        assertThrows(DuplicateKeyException.class, () -> {
            downloadJobRepository.save(copyOf1);
        });

    }
```

This test case is a simplified extract from a larger system and there the workaround from above does not work, so there is something I don't understand about what's going on here. Could someone please help explain what is happening here?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure that `{ state: "ACTIVE" }` is a valid partial expression. You may use `{ state: { $eq: 'ACTIVE' } }` instead, which actually works.

Also, the `state` field shouldn't be part of the`unique` clause.

```
db.jobs.createIndex(
    { name: 1 },
    { unique: true, partialFilterExpression: { state: { $eq: 'ACTIVE' } } }
)
```

Result:

```
db.jobs.getIndexes()
[
{
    "v" : 2,
    "key" : {
        "_id" : 1
    },
    "name" : "_id_",
    "ns" : "test.jobs"
},
    {
        "v" : 2,
        "unique" : true,
        "key" : {
            "name" : 1
        },
        "name" : "name_1",
        "ns" : "test.jobs",
        "partialFilterExpression" : {
            "state" : {
                "$eq" : "ACTIVE"
            }
        }
    }
]
```

Testing:

```
// first active job
> db.jobs.save({name: "first", state: "ACTIVE"})
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })
// second active job
> db.jobs.save({name: "two", state: "ACTIVE"})
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })
// another first active job, should fail
> db.jobs.save({name: "first", state: "ACTIVE"})
WriteResult({
    "nInserted" : 0,
    "writeError" : {
        "code" : 11000,
        "errmsg" : "E11000 duplicate key error collection: test.jobs index: name_1 dup key: { name: \"first\" }"
    }
})
```

- 

```
// no problem saving multiple "timed out" first jobs:
> db.jobs.save({name: "first", state: "TO"})
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })
> db.jobs.save({name: "first", state: "TO"})
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })
> db.jobs.find({name: "first"})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("617daaa99a17a2b387e4a2ca"), "name" : "first", "state" : "ACTIVE" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("617daaed9a17a2b387e4a2cd"), "name" : "first", "state" : "TO" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("617daaf69a17a2b387e4a2ce"), "name" : "first", "state" : "TO" }

// also no problem updating an "active" job to "timed out"
> db.jobs.update({"_id" : ObjectId("617daaa99a17a2b387e4a2ca")}, {$set: {state: "TO"}})
WriteResult({ "nMatched" : 1, "nUpserted" : 0, "nModified" : 1 })
> db.jobs.find({name: "first"})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("617daaa99a17a2b387e4a2ca"), "name" : "first", "state" : "TO" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("617daaed9a17a2b387e4a2cd"), "name" : "first", "state" : "TO" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("617daaf69a17a2b387e4a2ce"), "name" : "first", "state" : "TO" }

// since there are no active first jobs by now, no problem to update one as such
> db.jobs.update({"_id" : ObjectId("617daaa99a17a2b387e4a2ca")}, {$set: {state: "ACTIVE"}})
WriteResult({ "nMatched" : 1, "nUpserted" : 0, "nModified" : 1 })

//but updating another job is prohibited:
> db.jobs.update({"_id" : ObjectId("617daaed9a17a2b387e4a2cd")}, {$set: {state: "ACTIVE"}})
WriteResult({
    "nMatched" : 0,
    "nUpserted" : 0,
    "nModified" : 0,
    "writeError" : {
        "code" : 11000,
        "errmsg" : "E11000 duplicate key error collection: test.jobs index: name_1 dup key: { name: \"first\" }"
    }
})
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, @Ori Dar - I'm not sure that affects my case, as I could exhibit those cases, but only using the "workaround" in my code above. So I think the Mongo index setup is ok... but something about Java Spring Data and this case is confusing to me.